# Can a singleplayer world be turned into a multiplayer world?

Tags: terraria-console

I was playing Terraria on Xbox One and my friend wanted to join my singleplayer world. Can I use that world in multiplayer?

Comment: I think you just need to invite him to the game through your friends list and he should be able to join any world. It's been a while since I've played so I can't be 100% certain

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go into the multiplayer tab on the title screen, press host a game, and then you should be able to pick your character and world.